# Where can i find the reference to a link giving an error?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, libgdx

Using libgdx and just trying to get the HTML version of the basic setup is driving me crazy. I get this error

Loading modules
   com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition
      [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/me/mygdxgame/GwtDefinition.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method

this happens unless i actually named my app com.me.mygdxgame

i can't find any mention of this link(com.me.mygdxgame) any where in any of the .xml files and don't know where eclipse is getting it from. It gets that error on loading the index.html file but even in it the links are correct. Any help would be appreciated. 
and i just searched for any mention of mygdxgame in all file in the workspace and got back 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found out what it was.
The war directory was somehow getting cross linked to a same named game so no matter how many times i remade it it was getting linked to an old folder i had before. So even though all the directory's in the properties looked right the war folder was wrong. to fix it i had to un-check the "This project has a war folder" from the property's |Google|Web Application tab apply it then i tried running it as a web app it told me i didn't have a war directory so it would not run. That part may not be necessary but when i rechecked the box and re-selected the only war folder it would let me. the next time i ran i got to re-select the war folder from a full directory and not just my  projects directory. This fixed the problem.

Just to clarify Eclipse seems to save war folder information by the name of the folder in which the project is contained what happened in my case was i had created a folder called MyGame in which i stored a project named com.me.mygdxgame the default for using libgdx. later i renamed that folder MyGame_old and started over with a new MyGame folder in which i named the project anything else doesn't matter the point is it never asked me for the war folder when i went to run it the first time, it just assumed somehow i was using the old one which was now in MyGame_old don't know how it found it but it did. so it was reading old files with bad links.

hopefully this might help someone else with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error as well but your suggested fix didn't work for me. After some investigating, here is what I did to get it to run: open the "Run Configurations" for the project and then click on the "Arguments" tab. Remove any reference to the com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefintion in the arguments.

After this, project ran error free. Hope this helps.

Comment: must of been a slightly different problem because with mine the arguments were always empty.

Answer (score 0):

After reading some posts it was clear that this problem was caused by GWT. One main reason for this problem is you are constantly reusing the same port and GWT is reusing the old properties.
There is really simple fix for this.

right click -html project.
Run-> run configuration.
Go to server tab.
check automatically select an unused port.

Press apply and